# Can tight hip flexors cause tight hamstrings?

Tags: stretching, flexibility, hamstring, tendons, calf

Today I noticed that when I sit like this:

[image: Sitting cross legged https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sitting_on_a_chair_with_legs_crossed_in_swimming_shorts.jpg]

My left leg goes comfortably all the way down, but my right leg won't. It won't go down past 45 degrees unless stretched. Does this mean that the right hip flexors are tight and can this cause tight hamstring and calf muscles?

What stretches should I be working on to release this? I've tried basic hamstring stretches without success.

Comment: Welcome to Physical Fitness.SE! Athlean-X has an [excellent video](https://youtu.be/KCADorwJ6Ik) on hip flexor tightness and IIRC around the 4 minute mark he illustrates a simple test to determine if your hip flexors are not up to snuff. This doesn't really answer your Achilles tendon problem, but may shed some light on the issue?

Comment: I don't believe this is off topic at all. This has NOTHING to do with "health" - it has EVERYTHING to do with working out correctly, which is what this board is about. To me, it's entirely absurd that good posts like these get flagged as off topic.

@Benjamin To me it looks like your IT band is tight, your hip flexors *might* be tight, but sitting like that mainly tests for IT band inflexibility.

Comment: @VSO - I understand your frustration, but medical diagnosis type questions have always been off topic. Even on Health/Medical Science, "diagnose me" type questions are off topic. Additionally, even if this wasn't a "why do I hurt here?" type of question, there is nothing about fitness or working out in the post. If you would like, you can raise the question on meta and see how the community feels about it.

Comment: There is a special clinical test for this called the FABER (or Patrick) Test. This test is commonly utilized to detect hip, lumbar spine, or sacroiliac joint pathology.    https://www.physio-pedia.com/FABER_Test

Comment: @JohnP I know whoever marked this is just following the agreed on rules, so I am def not trying to be hostile. It's just, that in my experience a lot injuries are DIRECTLY sports related, and extremely common. There is value in knowing what causes shin splints, for example. It's not medical advice, it's fitness advice. Anyway, I will bring it up in the meta once I am not too lazy, ty for the suggestion.

Comment: @JohnP  I edited it to remove all medical details and focus solely on stretching in line with the other questions in the related tab. Can you release the hold?

Comment: @Benjamin and there we have the main problem with this. Answers are nothing but "I'm guessing" which is horrible fit for the stack exchange format.

Comment: @VSO - See my reply to benjamin.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that the asymmetry you are observing has nothing to do with tightness or lack of stretching.  My guess is that the shape of your pelvis and/or your femoral head is asymmetric.  I've seen the same thing, but much worst, in a lady client of mine.  She has had two hip replacements, and one of the replacements had to be done twice (I guess they screwed up the first one).  When they repeat a hip replacement, they have to remove a lot more of your own bone.   As a result, her two hips are very asymmetric, and one of her knees won't go down when she crosses legs.

Comment: So your estimate is based on comparing  a lady with two hip replacements to an (apparently) healthy male with no hip replacements? I'm not really sure that's a logical correlation to make.

Comment: I could be wrong.